# rails 3 breadcrumbs_on_rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to configure breadcrumbs_on_rails with rails 3 application

I have added

```
gem 'breadcrumbs_on_rails'
```

into my gemfile

also, I have placed include BreadcrumbsOnRails::ControllerMixin

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

include BreadcrumbsOnRails::ControllerMixin

if defined?(Bundler)
....
```

into application.rb

But anyway I constantly getting error:

```
runnerw.exe C:\Ruby\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /script/rails server -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -e development
/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant BreadcrumbsOnRails (NameError)
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from /script/rails:6:in `require'
    from /script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
```

How to solve this error ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi friend the constant BreadcrumbsOnRails::ControllerMixin will be available after bundler loads your gem 'breadcrumbs_on_rails'.

But you are used BreadcrumbsOnRails::ControllerMixin before bundler loads you gem.

The gems are loaded after execution of the following lines.so you have to use

```
require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
 # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
   Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
 # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
include BreadcrumbsOnRails::ControllerMixin
```

Here is the doc for your gem.

https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I have placed include BreadcrumbsOnRails::ControllerMixin after the bundler, but still getting the same error - /config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant BreadcrumbsOnRails::ControllerMixin (NameError)

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the docs provided by @soundar, I don't see ControllerMixin anywhere in the source or documentation.  Nor do I see any need to put anything in config/application.rb